# How can I fill a list holding a struct in C# using loop?

Tags: c#, generics, console-application

I am new to C# and I tried this with arrays a week ago( a CGPA Calculator) now I want to replicate the console app using generics I just learnt

Tried using a dictionary but only takes two items

```
struct CourseInfo
{
    public string courseName {get; set;}
    public int load {get; set;}
    public char grade {get; set;} 
}

class Gene
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var courseList = new List<CourseInfo>();

    Console.WriteLine("How many courses are you offering? ");
    int no_of_courses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter them");
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_courses; i++)
    {
      courseList.Add(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    foreach (var course in courseList)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"{course.courseName} {course.load} {course.grade}");   
    }
  }
```

The First error was:

> The best overloaded method match for  System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(NewGene.CourseInfo) has some invalid arguments

second was:

> Argument #1 cannot convert string expression to type `NewGene.CourseInfo'"

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the list with `CourseInfo` structs, not strings.  You can do this inline with property intializers:

Change this:

```
courseList.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

to this:

```
courseList.Add(new CourseInfo() { courseName = Console.ReadLine() });
```

More readable code, however, might look like this:

```
var courseInfo = new CourseInfo();
courseInfo.courseName = Console.ReadLine();
courseInfo.load = 3;
courseInfo.grade = 'A';
courseList.Add(courseInfo);
```

Comment: Ok, I did this but then the loop only takes courseInfo.courseName. How do I make the loop take all three properties in one or more ReadLine() object?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, and your other structure members are an `int` and a `char`.  You'll need to convert these as necessary.  int.Parse() will convert a string to an int.  You can use the  `[0]` operator on a string to get the first `char`. If you get stuck, I suggest creating a separate question on that topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just did that using three ReadLine() and converting the necessary ones now it works . But do you have help for me on how I can do it just one ReadLine() ? so that user can enter the three properties once?